# Unable to generate readable PDF using iText 7's HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument method

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I am trying to use itext7 and itext7.pdfhtml to generate a PDF from some HTML on a server and I then return the written-to `MemoryStream` as a `FileContentResult` to the client.  However, when the client receives the PDF all they get is an unopenable PDF file which, if the file extension is changed to a .txt, can be seen to contain nothing more than "%PDF-1.7%âãÏÓ".

Having experimented with `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf` I was able to get the simple content in the example below to work (at least the body of it anyway); however, I believe I need `HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument` instead now since I need the ability to add a footer and set the page size and margins on the resultant PDF with settings not held within the HTML passed in (in other words I need the iText `Document` object to manipulate).

Here is the code I am using...

```
public static byte[] GeneratePdfFromHtml(Action<Document> pdfModifier)
{
    //Gives the converter some very simple HTML for it to create something with!
    var html = "<html><head><title>Extremely Basic Title</title></head><body>Extremely Basic Content</body></html>";

    using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream))
    using (var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(html, pdfWriter))
    {
        //Passes the document to a delegated function to perform some content, margin or page size manipulation
        pdfModifier(document);

        //Returns the written-to MemoryStream containing the PDF.   
        return workStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This was the version I had working but it lacks the object I need to pass to my delegate.

```
public static byte[] GeneratePdfFromHtml(Action<Document> pdfModifier)
{
    //Gives the converter some very simple HTML for it to create something with!
    var html = "<html><head><title>Extremely Basic Title</title></head><body>Extremely Basic Content</body></html>";

    using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream))
    {
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, pdfWriter);

        //No longer able to call this delegate as there is no Document object to use.
        //pdfModifier(document);

        //Returns the written-to MemoryStream containing the PDF.   
        return workStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *version* you *had working* you used `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf`. This call internally also creates a `Document` object but closes it before returning.

Closing the `Document` object causes all data of the generated PDF still in memory to be flushed to the result stream which then gets finalized with a PDF trailer.

Thus, your working version returns a finished, complete PDF file.

In your new code, though, you use `HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument`. This call returns the used `Document` object but does not close it: You after all still want to use it for some manipulations.

As you don't close the `Document` object before calling `return workStream.ToArray()`, you return an incomplete PDF, in your case only a PDF header section.

Thus, you have to close that `Document` object before retrieving the bytes from your `MemoryStream`, e.g. explicitly like this

```
using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream))
using (var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(html, pdfWriter))
{
    //Passes the document to a delegated function to perform some content, margin or page size manipulation
    pdfModifier(document);

    document.Close();

    //Returns the written-to MemoryStream containing the PDF.   
    return workStream.ToArray();
}
```

or implicitly like this:

```
using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream))
{
    using (var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(html, pdfWriter))
    {
        //Passes the document to a delegated function to perform some content, margin or page size manipulation
        pdfModifier(document);
    }

    //Returns the written-to MemoryStream containing the PDF.   
    return workStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I should've mentioned, I previously tried (before to `workStream.ToArray()`) `pdfWriter.Flush()`, which made no difference at all; and `pdfWriter.Close()` which then caused `System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.` to be thrown when dispose on the document was called.  However, I've now also tried your implicit approach and it's actually worked!  As a side note, I was also getting an `iText.Kernel.PdfException: Document has no pages.` exception for the actual HTML I'm passing in in my real method - this seems to have fixed that problem also!  Thanks.