# Error generating pdf with iText.Html2pdf C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have the function below that creates a pdf in C#. However, when executing the `HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument()` function I receive the following error message `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not defined for an instance of an object.'`. can anybody help me?

```
public static Byte[] CreatePdf(string html)
{
    Byte[] bytes;
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();

    iText.Layout.Font.FontProvider fontProvider = new iText.Html2pdf.Resolver.Font.DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
    fontProvider.AddDirectory(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\");
    converterProperties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var pdfWriter = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(ms))
        {
            pdfWriter.SetCloseStream(false);
                using (var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(html, pdfWriter, converterProperties))
                {
                }
        }
        ms.Position = 0;
        bytes = ms.ToArray();
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

I created my function based on [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232070/unable-to-generate-readable-pdf-using-itext-7s-htmlconverter-converttodocument), but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: The error message should tell you _what_ reference is null. Are you sure it's occurring from the `ConvertToDocument` method call? If so, are you sure your three parameters are non-null and correct?

Comment: Please share the stack trace of the error.